# Words with hyphen are not recognized in attribute based routing mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Unable to match few urls with MVC5 routing attributes

Route attribute

```
[Route("{language}/{moviename}-{year:int}-{tracktitle}-movie")]
```

Matches with (both works)

```
localdomain/English/Transformers-2013-ABC-movie

localdomain/English/Wolf-of-wall-street-2013-ABC-movie
```

But it is not matching when `ABC` is added with one more word `DEF` for track title.

```
localdomain/English/Transformers-2013-ABC-DEF-movie
```

Comment: Can't you use regex in Route matching? Using `{tracktitle:.*(?:\-movie$)}` or somemthing similar might work.

Comment: On the other hand I might have been spoiled by nancy...

Comment: Maybe ;-) the regex engine is not recognizing

 [Route("{language}/{moviename}-{year:int}-{tracktitle:regex(.*(?:\\-movie$))}")]

Comment: I do know that you can create custom Route Constraints, you may be best off using a custom regex and sticking that in your route constraint.

Comment: Agreed, Plan B. Wondering what is going wrong when it works correctly for movie and not working with track title ? Isn't it a bug ?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here, but try `[Route("{language}/{moviename}-{year:int}-{*tracktitle}-movie")]`.

Comment: Unable to register as route url,

A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.
Parameter name: routeUrl

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate your parameters with '/' rather than trying to hyphenate them. Generally hyphenating refers to it being a single word/related phrase, where in your case, it's separate distinguishable items

i.e.: `[Route("{language}/{moviename}/{year:int}/{tracktitle}/movie")]`

**EDIT:**

try using a combination of catch-all and regex matching

```
[Route("{language}/{moviename}-{year:int}-{*tracktitle:regex(^-movie$)}")]
```

then, in your action, remove the string "-movie" from your track title, but it should allow you to use your convention

Comment: Already using - hyphens for other urls, also any impact on seo score ?

Comment: don't know if you'd see enough impact on seo to make a difference

see my edit with an alternate method using regex and catch-all

Comment: catch all not working. Runtime error

A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.
Parameter name: routeTemplate

Comment: do you have the catch all at the end of the route? that error usually occurs when you try to place the catch all in any place other than the end of the route

Comment: using like this       
[Route("{language:regex(a)}/{moviename}-{year:int}-{*tracktitle:regex(^-movie$)}")]

Comment: If I remove the '-' from the route w/ the catch-all and replace with '/' it works fine. Only think I'd suggest if you want to continue with the hyphens might be to create your own Route Handler. It doesn't look like what you want to do is possible with the built-in RouteHandler